# SQL - join multiplying data

Tags: sql, join

I need to produce a synthetic table from 2 tables but one of them is tricky.

First table (sample):

[image]

Second table (sample also) :
I want to use it to find the 'store' of each 'pers'

[image]

What i want at the end :
(and i want to keep the 'zero' if sum_of_duration is null)

[image]

My first code :

```
SELECT 
QRT,
STORE,
sum(DURATION) as SUM_of_DURATION
FROM   T1
LEFT JOIN T2
    on T1.PERS=T2.PERS
group by QRT, STORE
```

But my 'Sum_of_durations' are out of the roof because of multiple joins induced by table 2 i guess.

Any help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove duplicates before joining:

```
SELECT T1.QRT, T2.STORE,
      SUM(T1.DURATION) as SUM_of_DURATION
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT QRT, PERS
      FROM t2
     ) t2
     ON T1.PERS = T2.PERS
GROUP BY T1.QRT, T2.STORE;
```

Comment: Sorry didn't see your answer. We posted exactly same answer. I am deleting mine.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur . . . I don't actually care about such things.  I assume that when you started to answer, mine wasn't here and I answered while you were creating yours.  Each answer has a timestamp.  For equivalent answers, I encourage OPs to choose the first correct one.  But sometimes there is something about one of the answers that resonates with the OP.